# Search specific on User Properties

Tags: people-search

I was able to put down something like 
JobTitle:"GIS" in the search box for people search in our dev environment, but I found that I just can't use the same way to bring results back in test and live environment.

Could it a security side thing or any configuration is missed out.
I made a comparison between dev and test, field properties, crawled and managed properties all setup in the same way.

Comment: What version of SharePoint?

Answer (score 0):

To troubleshoot this you have to determine if your 3 farms are importing profiles in the same way. Look at the User Profiles and compare attributes of the Job Title property. Next ensure that each farm is crawling the user profiles on SPS3 (or SPS3S for SSL). Only then will you get the same results in all 3 environments.